# How to retrieve all contacts in Windows Store app using c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm writing Universal app (WinStore 8.1 + WinPhone 8.1). For my requirements I need to retrieve all device contacts. It's OK on WinPhone - here is code how I do that:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
```

But how to do that in WinStore app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by design I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Tt's not possible to get the information from the people app. It works within calendar, mail or messenger because they're all technically contained within the same app and are able to use each other's data and violate normal rules.

You can always use the ContactPicker.
[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1) might help.